# How To Dispatch Array In VueJS

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I am having trouble dispatching an array of data to the backend. I tried adding `[]` to the dispatch variables and to the backend, but it only gives me the last data passed to the backend. My goal is to `match each data to another table with multiple data that is the exactly identical to each other`. I used a multiple selection table to get multiple data by the way. I replaced the equal sign with push but now my error is `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. IT's probably because of the backend now but I don't know how to retrieve an array to the backend.

Frontend

```
<script>
data(){
return {
   gatheredData: {
        answerId: [],
        studentAccessId: [],
        testItemId: [],
        answer: [],
      },
}
},
methods:{  
getChecked(selected3) {
      for (var s = 0; s < selected3.length; s++) {
        this.gatheredData.studentAccessId.push(selected3[s].studentAccessId);
        this.gatheredData.testItemId.push(selected3[s].testItemId);
        this.gatheredData.studentanswer.push(selected3[s].studentanswer);

        this.$store
          .dispatch("SUBMIT_SCORE", {
            total: this.selected3.length,
            token2: this.token,
            studentAccessId2: this.gatheredData.studentAccessId,
            testItemId2: this.gatheredData.testItemId,
            studentanswer2: this.gatheredData.studentanswer,
          })
         
      }
    },
</script>
```

index.js (Store)

```
 SUBMIT_SCORE ({ commit }, payload) {
        console.log(payload.studentAccessId)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios
            .post('http://localhost/MyComposer/', payload, {
              params: {
                submitId: 14
              }
            })
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data)
              resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              reject(error)
            })
        })
      },
```

Backend

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['submitId']) && $_GET['submitId'] == 14) {
            $scoreData = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $decodedScoreData = json_decode($scoreData);
            $total = $decodedScoreData->{'total'};
            // $answerId = $decodedScoreData->{'answerId'};
            $testItemId = $decodedScoreData->{'testItemId'};
            $token = $decodedScoreData->{'token'};
            $studentAccessId = $decodedScoreData->{'studentAccessId'};
            $studentanswer = $decodedScoreData->{'studentanswer'};


            $db->where('AccessId', $token);
            $db->where('StudentAccessId', $studentAccessId);
            $db->where('TestItemId', $testItemId);
            $getStudentAnswers = $db->get('answertable');


            $flag = 0;
            foreach ($getStudentAnswers as $gsa) {
                if ($gsa['StudentAnswer'] === $studentanswer && $gsa['StudentAccessId'] === $studentAccessId && $gsa['TestItemId'] === $testItemId) {
                    $flag = 1;
                } else {
                    $flag = 2;
                }
            }

            $updateFlag = array(
                'Flag' => $flag,
            );

            $newFlag = $db->update('answertable', $updateFlag);
            if ($newFlag) {
                echo json_encode($newFlag);
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

(this.gatheredData.studentAccessId) This field does not look like array type in your code. While it loops last one will be assigned.

Refer to below.

```js
gatheredData {
  studentAccessId: []
  ...
 }
 
 ....
 loop {
   this.gatheredData.studentAccessId.push();
 }
```

Or I think you can use the selected3 parameter, since it seems it is already array type.

Comment: The push works but when I passed it to backend, it gives me an error: `Cannot read property push of underfined`. I added the Store so you can also see the Vuex actions.

Comment: I can not find your array which cause the error, could you post your code containing .push()

Comment: I updated the question now. Also, I added the data for gatheredData object. It's all arrays now.

Comment: You dont have studentanswer in gatherdData.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Thanks for the answer. All I needed was the push all this time.